# Communicating with ESP8266 via SerialMonitor

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I was following [this tutorial](https://maker.pro/esp8266/tutorial/esp8266-tutorial-how-to-control-anything-from-the-internet) where I could follow everything up until point when I needed to communicate via the Serial Monitor of the Arduino IDE.

This means that I was able to:

- Have the correct wiring
- Being able to 'flash' some code to the ESP8266

And this means that I was unable to:

- Send AT commands via the Serial Monitor with the Arduino IDE.

The messages that I send are appended with both NL & CR, and I use a baudrate of 115200 for the communication.

At this point I am at a loss what else I can try... how can I further debug something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think you properly flashed the ESP, you should be able to see it as a node in your network.
Start there.

If you do not see it as a node on your network, you did NOT successfully complete the first few steps.

The other issue might be timing. Keep the baud rate at the max speed on the arduino for receive. turn them both off. turn the Arduion on first - wait a couple seconds. The rduino is not running the receive code the instant it boots. After a few seconds, power on the ESP. You may not see the text you expect, but you should at least see goobly-gook.

If you do see goobly-gook, you will need to pick the right baud rate so the arduino matches the ESP, and boot them as pairs.

If you do not see goobly-gook, check your wiring. If you are confident in your wiring, buy a new ESP as you likely burnt it out in the recent past with bad wiring :(

Comment: Thanks for answering. Indeed, I just checked my local network and it isnt there. I do receive goobly-gook from time to time. So I think I still have faith in the ESP8266's life...
I will check the timing issue in a sec and then go to bed. Thanks for this sanity check, much appreciated

Comment: I checked the timing issue just now, and that seems to have it fixed. So first power on the Arduino, and then connect the ESP8266. Thanks!

Comment: The trick is this... The arduino does not immediately boot to the code you upload. It first boots to code that waits for the CPU for a second or so for a code update. (This is so that even if you manage to get an infinite loop in your code that you can push a new image in!) That hot second can cause nightmares!

I bet that will fix steps 1 and 2 as well. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If you flashed the code in the tutorial you linked to, you wouldn’t be able to send AT commands to the module because it’s not running AT firmware. The module only responds to AT commands because it’s running a program that makes it do that. If the AT firmware was installed, you overwrote it when you flashed the code from the tutorial.

If you want to use AT commands with it you’ll need to flash the [AT firmware](https://github.com/espressif/esp-at). Note that the most recent versions don’t support the ESP8266, so you’ll need to follow the instructions in the README to use an older version.

Comment: The device is connecting to the wifi with the crednetials given and then seems like it has a web interface. When the web interface is adjusted the ESP woudl send data via UART to the arduino.

None of this process uses AT commands.

The OP was experiencing no logging information beign sent to the arduino via UART from the ESP.

Comment: OP said in the original question: "And this means that I was unable to: Send AT commands via the Serial Monitor with the Arduino IDE."